# Storing SVGs into a database

Tags: database, svg

Working on an app that serves mostly customers with businesses (freelancers, tradesmen, sole traders, etc). Trying to implement a functionality that lets the users upload their logos which will be stored in a database along with their user details. The logos can be stored with jpeg, png, gif, and SVG. With jpeg, png, and gif, to store them, we encoded them into base64 string.

Just want to hear your thoughts about how to save SVGs into databases?

Comment: I don't get why you need to implement a different algorith for svg. It stores well as base64 and you can work with it just as with any other format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would simply store the SVG as a text field in the database. You should probably have a meta "mime_type" field for your record, set to "image/svg+xml". So that when you read it again, and either render it serverside, or inject it client side - you will know that you will not have to base64 decode it.

You could also have a meta field in the database table like "encoding" that your code could react to when reading it.

Just make sure that you are serving the image as the mime type 'image/svg+xml'

Answer (score 1):

Svg’s can be stored as a string as well. SVG’s are buily out of an path.

This is what i would do.